# Safe to change the status bar color to black?

Tags: ios, xcode

Currently, my status bar color is white. I want to make it black because my app would look better that way. My question is, is it "safe" to do so, or does it go against Apple guidelines? Would my app not be approved?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are allowed to use either of color `statusbar` in `iOS`.

From [Apple doc.s](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/ios/bars/status-bars/)

> The visual style of the status bar’s text and indicators is either
>   light or dark, and can be set globally for your app or individually
>   for different screens. A dark status bar works well above
>   light-colored content and a light status bar works well above
>   dark-colored content.

[image]